# Null values from multipart/form data upload using fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code. It works well on postman and fiddler but on react native I keep getting null value. I have search for several solutions but none solved my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Below is a sample of my fetch method

```
handleSubmitButton = () => {

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file" , photo);
formdata.append("Uid", "103");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formdata,
   headers: {
        //Header Definition
       
        'Content-Type':
        'multipart/form-data',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
         'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache',  
      },
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("url", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
   .then((responseJson) => {
      
        console.log('response', responseJson);
         if (
          responseJson.toString() ===
          'Successful'
        ) else {
          // setErrortext(responseJson.msg);

          console.log(responseJson);
         alert(responseJson);
          return;
        }
        
      }) .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
        alert(error);
      });
 };
```

My Request Api from C#. The code receives the picture and users id to be used in the database.

```
[Route("Uploadprofilepic")]
                [HttpPost]
                public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUserImage()
                {

                Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                try
                {
                    
                    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
                    string filePath = "";
                    foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

                        var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                        if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                        {

                            int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 5; //Size = 1 MB  

                            IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                            var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                            var extension = ext.ToLower();
                            if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                            {

                                var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");

                                dict.Add("error", message);
                                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                            }
                            else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                            {

                                var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 5 mb.");

                                dict.Add("error", message);
                                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                var newFileName = String.Concat(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), postedFile.FileName);

                                filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploadimages/" + newFileName + extension);

// get other form data key here that is users id


//var uploadPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/") + @"/Uploads";
                    //Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadPath);
                    //var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadPath);
                    //await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
                    //foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
                    //{
                    //    foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                    //    {
                    //        
                    //    }
                    //}
                                using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
                                {// 
                                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                                    {
                                        con.Close();
                                    }
                                    con.Open();

                                    string com = "";

                                    // com = "Select wallet_id,wallet_name from Wallets where sub_acctype='Prepayment' or sub_acctype='Regular'";
                                    //}else
                                    //{
                                    com = "insert into imagetempt (imagenm,status) values (@a1,@a2)  ";

                                    //}
                                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(com, con);
                                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", newFileName);
                                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", "False");//First_name
                                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    con.Close();

                                    transactionScope.Complete();
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        var message1 = string.Format("filePath");
                        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1); ;
                    }
                    var res = string.Format("Please Upload an image.");
                    dict.Add("error", res);
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   
                    dict.Add("error ", res);
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you try `Request.Form.Files` instead `Request.Files`?